# Hide and Show elements across multiple pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, session-storage

Is there a way to save the state of an element across multiple pages? Maybe using session or local storage perhaps?

Functionality like this is what I want to achieve. But I want it to remember what is shown and hidden upon exiting and returning to the page.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: yes, use localStorage.setItem('display', 'block') and use localStorage.getItem('display')

Comment: Doing this: `localStorage.setItem('display', x.style.display )` saves the state and it updates when I select the button again, however on return to the page, although the key is saved, there is no style defined in the html.

Comment: instead of saving x.style.display,var dis;  if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block"; dis = 'block'
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none"; dis ='none'
    }

Comment: use variable and assign value in if else ,  setItem and getItem to see the last stored value

Comment: I am able to see the last stored value in storage and it is updating when I press the button. In the html it is changing the style to display block and display none. However on return to the page there is no style assigned to the html element, and so it is displayed again by default, even though session storage has a value assigned to the display key.

Comment: then create onload function on body tag and localStorage.getItem('display') and add x.style.display = localStorage.getItem('display')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option localStorage and onload function

1. Use locaStorage.setItem and localStorage.getItem to set and fetch values from localstorage
2. Use onload function on body to set display from the localstorage

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  console.log(x.style.display)
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      localStorage.setItem('display','block')
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem('display','none')
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
  console.log(localStorage)
}

function checkDisplay(){
      var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
      x.style.display = localStorage.getItem('display');
}
```

```html
<body onload="checkDisplay()">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>
  
  <body>
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/BxabBz

Comment: I realise following your last comment I was not using a further function to check and it was defaulting to display none. This answer works perfectly for me. Thank you.